# Deploying a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric (multiple organizations)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I implemented hyperledger composer [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial) and created a simple business network definition. Then I deployed it through composer and  implemented it's rest APIs through composer-rest-server. Now I want to add one more peer to it on a different machine (PC) which can access the Blockchain I previously created. I followed this [Deploying a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric (multiple organizations)](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org), but in this tutorial, the network is configured using docker containers, with both organizations' fabric networks, on the same machine.

**My Question:


1. What are the differences between multiple organizations using docker containers (on the same machine) and using multiple machines (PC)?


2. How to implement this with multiple machines (PC) using Hyplerledger Composer?** 


Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered on Hyperledger Rocket Chat:

The tutorial you refer to (Multi Organisation on one PC) is used to illustrate the Composer Aspects of a Multi Organisation - Multi Peer configuration. It is not necessary to use Docker Containers to build a Fabric, but it is easier and the majority choose to do it that way.

It is easy for Composer to work with a Multi Machine setup - you just create a different connection.json file to 'point' to the various addresses! The real question is how to implement a Multi-Org Hyperledger Fabric.

Docker Compose is the tool used for a Development Fabric and for the tutorials and it provides networking between the component containers, but Docker Compose is only really intended for a single machine. To work with multiple machines Kubernetes or Docker Swarm are better choices (or cloud hosting) and certainly something other than Docker Compose is required for production.
There are however a couple of tutorials that can be used for learning or PoC - I haven't tried them, but others in the community have:
https://www.skcript.com/svr/setting-up-a-blockchain-business-network-with-hyperledger-fabric-and-composer-running-in-multiple-physical-machine/
https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f

Comment: @R Thatcher: Thank you very much! I have one more question with Deploying a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric (multiple organizations). In a blockchain is peer to peer network, when one node or peer (Docker Container or PC) is down and then all network in blockchain is working find. And in this tutorial, How can we testing alice and bob work in this tutorial is mean, can I use composer-rest-server in 2 terminal, one is alice@trade-network and other is bob@trade-network? How we know when one peer is down or problem?

Comment: Composer and Fabric should be OK and continue to run if a Peer goes down. However in the MultiOrg configuration I think there is only one Orderer so that will cause problems. (Also I think there is an issue with Fabric in a multi-Orderer configuration if 1 goes down.)
In a Production scenario you would have some monitoring tools setup to detect any failed components.